# Why does TypeScript unable to identify the properties shared among mixins?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance, mixins

I'm trying to implement **mixins** in TypeScript.

Here's the code:

```
type Mixable = new (...args: any[]) => {};

class Base {
  constructor(protected _a: string, protected _b: string) {}
}

const A = (Base: Mixable) => class A extends Base {
  a() {
    console.log(this._a);
    return this;
  }
};

const B = (Base: Mixable) => class B extends Base {
  b() {
    console.log(this._b);
    return this;
  }
};

const C = A(B(Base));

const o = new C("a","b");

o.a().b();
```

But unfortunately the compiler is failed to identify the properties shared among the mixins, chain methods and emitted errors.

[Here's the playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgDwIYCMA20C8UB2EDuUAFAHRlIBOA5gM4BcUSOIA2gLoCUUmAfFAN4BfANwBYAFASAxmiQ0aUAEJzo-CVChSA9jhrAKAVynAtFImApbgEYxAAmUAPpIGeinBxUANFAtWb1g6OKK76HlRcQhKCEtI6elAAgtzEyjQQDPDI6BBcvJqy8klQEAjWOHYKaarqjESRtRrauloYJGhaVETAABZwNCTOHGLiGhoUEMAGFDhQvf0jGjHiIrHizQmKKUTVmYioGHl8MnJVJWUQFVUqArUo9bejYxutEO2d3X0DwcONUBNTGZzL6LKDLVaSdbxYBQADCKUSOx2Kg4v0hGxhWhSeEIsKIACIkPivPiUPi0RItCQkPUSPc0UA).

P.S. If you run this, it runs successfully, and generates the expected output without any JS error.

Comment: `const A = (Base: Mixable) => class A extends Base` - "Base" here has no relation to `class Base` it is just parameter of type `Mixable`

Comment: Docs on mixins https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Comment: @AlekseyL. `Base` is passed as a parameter to the mixin generator, and properties available in `Base` are also available in `A` and `B`. Feel free to see the JS implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access properties `_a` and `_b` you need to enforce that the class which you are applying the mixin to has these properties.

Also mixins can be tricky in typescript with `protected` properties, so I made them `public`.

```
interface HasAB {
  _a: string;
  _b: string;
}

type Mixable = new (...args: any[]) => HasAB

class Base {
  constructor(public _a: string, public _b: string) {}
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJwM4EEBCyDeAsAFDLID6cAXMhmFKAOYDcJZ5ARjXQyCyQF8SJMAE8ADigCywAB5wOAGxQBeZCAgB3ZAAoAdAbhRGGGnBCiA2gF0AlMhUA%20NJlzDiCRZgzIcmFESkyAgA9iA8AK4IYCFQOuIRSsAIFNS09EwANMgJSSmc3Bl89vhCxGUkoeFgyFgOun4YEDQy8koQ9k7BXhg%20dRCykCAAJj6NAWzIcDq2NGAAFsA%20gWRkVRghynqKIYw6C0t6lLasQWRQEGARUCDIBxinZGUCp5VhdL71OuMtcgrKnWcnm8nwGQ1Gvn8BEmHBmc0Wy0ma3emwg212%20wRRw4JyRyAuVxudwRj2Qz1eHneNQAwvUsN9vv5bLjiG9qsgQvUNNpqToAERwPmZPkcPkskghPTTWx6WEsoA)

This clears up your issue with accessing properties.

**Edit:**

I've been playing with this more and unfortunately mixins just to do not work well with non-public properties.  With [this setup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4rQN4FgBQ1oAcAnAewBcFhyATaAfTAC5oJTCBLAOwHMBuHPImQrU6AIyYt23Ptn7RgxDpICulYoQAU9Ca05cANGJ1SuASgxy8pABZsIAOnrQAvHTAy8V2w9qiXYj2gAXxwQ2WxOckIAMzBgBDhEABUAT3wEhAAPcg4qGHgIZFQYdGgAejLoZQg9eWLEwuhIaFI0hDkOBAB3aA17frBCLggmMA4UgG0AXVMmAqLICFCcHAUlUmgAQX8AHiToLJy8hoRU9IA%20DQBZNkyEKiYk82dzusWtg%20yEXJgbu5osLgmhpzIDPPJFBBiCAEPYQMQuBobHZHGBTIE8IQEKRlIQOC1vIEwkEZKtIRtYLt9odvsd5mcEJc-vdHs9XqB3pSaT9oMyAXJRCCLEC8GsoTC4Qikd5HKJ0ZZoFicXiCXYiaFSdgxRskP5NhpYAbEChFqZ5eFtdBiP5Oj0kBoAERgB36B2iB3mnDEexgEH2QXmoA) the composed classes are able to access the protected properties of the passed-in class, but they give us error TS4094 "Property '_a' of exported class expression may not be private or protected." because properties of a mixin must be public.

I'm not confident enough to say it's straight-up impossible, but if I were you I would consider a different design pattern.  You can add accessor methods `getA()` and `getB()` to your class `Base`.  Or you can define `readonly public` properties `a` and `b` which access the underlying `private` properties `_a` and `_b`.

Here's how that second case breaks down:

We define an `interface AB` which has `public` properties `a` and `b`.  Recall that all properties in a typescript interface are inherently `public`.

```
interface AB {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

We declare that something is considered `Mixable` if is can be created with the keyword `new` and if that created object has `a` and `b`.

```
type Mixable = new (...args: any[]) => AB;
```

We alter `Base` such that it implements `interface AB`, which will make it `Mixable`.  You can explicitly write `class Base implements AB` but you don't have to.  It will be assignable to `Mixable` as long as it can read properties `a` and `b`.  We use javascript getters to implement `a` and `b` as `readonly` properties which will read the private value of `_a` and `_b` but cannot modify them.

```
class Base {
  constructor( protected _a: string, protected _b: string) {}

  get a(): string {
    return this._a;
  }

  get b(): string {
    return this._b;
  }
}
```

Now for our mixins.  We say that the class to be mixed must be of type `Mixable`.  We use the generic `<T extends Mixable>(Mixed: T)` so that we know that the returned class will have all of the properties and methods of the passed-in class, not just those in `Mixable`.  This fixes the issues with chaining.

Note that I renamed the methods in your example because I used `a` and `b` as the names of the properties so I can't also use them as the name of the methods.

```
const A = <T extends Mixable>(Mixed: T) => class A extends Mixed {
  aMethod() {
    console.log(this.a);
    return this;
  }
};

const B = <T extends Mixable>(Mixed: T) => class B extends Mixed {
  bMethod() {
    console.log(this.b);
    return this;
  }
};
```

Now you no longer have issues with any of this:

```
const C = A(B(Base)); // fine because Base extends Mixable

const o = new C("a","b");

o.aMethod().bMethod(); // fine because o.aMethod() returns an object with all of the abilities of C.
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIICFkG8CwAoZZOALmQGcwpQBzAbn0ICNSKqQ78BfffMATwAOKALLAAHnEYAbFAF5kICAHdkACgB0muFGplScEHwDaAXQCUyWQD406ennwIpcMmWToXKXAWQIA9iCsAK4IYH5QqsgCUH6QoRAAJsgA%20iTklDQANFExcZBJyczpbNQWWNwOPtQQYESqZiwZ7NgMhMhQNUFQIMhgABbAZOqp9oQVrdW1jPWNJS0%20hB1gXT39g8OMo8gV43j%20gbWolsgAPAAqyBBikCAJbqIS0hBWqg%20JpGcW1r7OrmiX1wgt3u4kS80IcGENT6fgS9XBbX2ZD8MnUUj81FUayGcDMW0WnW6vQGZC2O3sjgCFHcx3OAJud2QD0kMhebwSHy%20NicLjcmCuDJBYjB3iYUP6sPhosRVJREDRGKxJPUjDxrQJyyJ2LJXApeyptQAwsdUKp0GbPGY1ZUkbU-MdFCpDaoAERwF2ZF2MF3W-B%20dSQ6GSswq8UwuF4oA)

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution. But at the end the base class will have protected properties and the mixins should be able to access those as long as they inherit the base, plus it should also support the method chaining. Either it is not yet achievable by TypeScript, or I am unable to find a workaround.

Comment: The problem with protected is that we need typescript understand that our Mixable class must have properties _a and _b, and typescript interface members are considered public.  There’s probably a way around this, I just don’t know it.  I know that if the mixin is adding properties they can only be public.  The docs recommend using _ notation so you know it’s supposed to be private/protected even though you can’t declare it as such.

Comment: Although I can do this as a dirty solution, but still TS should have resolved this. If we even make those public, it still fails to chain. Something is not working as expected, or am I missing something?

Comment: Here’s what you’re missing: you are confused about what the mixins always know to be true vs. what they can only know once a specific argument has been passed in.  You have created this confusion through your naming because the argument of the mixin and a specific class are both named Base, but as @Aleksey already pointed out, the argument Base has no relation to the class Base.  You will eventually pass the class Base to your mixin, but the mixin cannot possibly know this.  You would need to tell the mixin that its argument Base must extend the class Base, and obviously rename one.

Comment: It just occurred to be that using a generic will solve the chaining issue.  I‘ll edit my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys for your contributions. It added a huge value to the question.

Before I go further, let me explain my original intention and the misunderstanding raised from my code.

My primary goal to use mixins is to **decompose my large classes**. As because this will be applied in different classes, I am creating a helper module. In order to keep the example understandable, I posted a simpler implementation.

Regarding the `Base` identifier, I did not mean the `Base` argument is referring to the Base class, but the Parent (i.e. the base of the extension). Anyways, to get rid of the confusion I'll be using the identifier `Parent` instead.

So, here's what I've come up with which I believe is pretty much extensible. Please ignore the weird name `Libbable` (this is just to demonstrate the idea).

```
type Mixable<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

interface Libbable {
  x: string;
  a(): any;
}

type Mixin = Mixable<Libbable>;

class Lib {
  constructor(public x: string) {}
  a(): this { return this }
}

const A = <T extends Mixin>(Parent: T) => class extends Parent {
  a() {
    console.log(this.x);
    return this;
  }
};

const B = <T extends Mixin>(Parent: T) => class extends Parent {
  b() {
    return this.a();
  }
};

const L = A(B(Lib));
const o = new L("x");

o.a().b();
```

[Link to the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgDwIYCMA2EA8AVKBeKAbwF8A%20fKAOwgHcoAKAOmaQCcBzAZwC4olKQAbQC6ASnzlsAbgCwAKHlxKwCKwBmSAMbQAMnBQpUGIvKhQEvTsFZL2suWaT1RvfiHvF580JFiIlFPDI6Fh6BkYQpPbymmhInJxQYSYOUJoA9pRWrACumsDprPRgOehwmuaW1rbiJKZ8zrzAABZwiYRQrBDAOayUUC1tUJ5yIzGZVlAAghQ4UBAIKpQAJolBSqT0AApsEMq82OJ45LHxiQtLq1A7Xcopjs73ZmkT6RiMaOns9IOcjAiiezPTrdXr9X5A4byYjROQZLLAKAAIVmuAueyu60omxue2AByOJziCXmiwxiVxd0I9RQj2pqTMXR6fQGrT%20TkB9RGMK8cImiJ0FCm9CR9DCok5fIRUHSFGodB09AARAglZL5OlGBzGLTJUA)

---

Because of [the design issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30355), currently, TypeScript is not able to share non-public properties among mixins. I really look forward to being able to use this, otherwise, the powerful access modifiers are simply useless here.

As it is necessary to declare the methods in the Base class to use them in the mixins, they will be gets called once the applicable class methods of the mixins are called. This is not what I want to happen. JS allows us to get rid of this, but TS doesn't. If you have a better idea to achieve what I want, feel free to share.